# SQL - DATE Type format is YYYY-MM-DD, but UPDATE is format YYYYMMDD

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have set up my database and set a field with the `DATE`-Type. When I look into my database the format is: `YYYY-MM-DD` but I can only update this field when I insert this format: `YYYYMMDD` with my statement.

Why is the insert format a other one than the `DATE`-Type format?

My PDO statement:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE mitarbeiter SET abwesend_von = :abwesend_von, abwesend_bis = :abwesend_bis WHERE id = :id");
      $stmt->execute(array(
        ':abwesend_von' => $_POST['abwesend_von'],
        ':abwesend_bis' => $_POST['abwesend_bis'],
        ':id' => $_POST['mitarbeiternummer_abwesenheit']
      ));
```

My POST Data:

```
mitarbeiternummer_abwesenheit:26
abwesend_von:20171001
abwesend_bis:20171031
```

Some informations:

- Database: Server Version: 5.6.19-67.0-log
- Database: MySQL-Client-Version: 5.1.61
- Programming language is PHP

Comment: Write a function to convert from `YYYYMMDD` to `YYYY-MM-DD`. Consider using [`strftime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) and [`strftime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php).

Comment: Hey tadman, thanks for your comment, but I have no problem with the formatting. The problem is, that only this format `YYYYMMDD` is accepted from the database.

Comment: The database should be `YYYY-MM-DD` as per [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: thats correct tadman, but I can only insert this format: `YYYYMMDD` in my database with field type `DATE` and that's... crazy.

Comment: @Martin Keep in mind, without quotes delimiting it; 2017-01-05 (for example) is evaluated as 2017 minus 1 minus 5, the integer 2011; MySQL supports assigning to date types with 20170105 as well as '2017-01-05'. _I'm not personally familiar with the behavior of the php libraries' involved in parameterized queries; but a lot of such libraries in other languages rely on the data types of the parameters in order to handle them correctly, something which php can be very flexible about._

Comment: @Uueerdo, thanks for your hint. Two different formats would make sense, because it works. Can you tell me where you read this (perhaps a link)?

Comment: I don't recall reading it specifically anywhere, but I've found an official source that says as much and put it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Date and time values can be represented in several formats, such as
>   quoted strings or as numbers, depending on the exact type of the value
>   and other factors. For example, in contexts where MySQL expects a
>   date, it interprets any of '2015-07-21', '20150721', and 20150721 as a
>   date.

[source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html)

The parameterized mechanisms of the php library could be interpreting the parameter as something other than a string, resulting in the query being 
`... SET abwesend_von = 2017-01-05 ...` which is equivalent to `... SET abwesend_von = 2011 ...`; instead of `... SET abwesend_von = '2017-01-05' ...`

Comment: Many thanks for the reply and the source to this. You have helped me a lot. So there is no problem with it and everything goes as intended.

Answer (score 1):

The query should be something like:

```
UPDATE `foo_schema`.`foo` SET `foo_date`='2017-04-03' WHERE `id`='1';
```

as an example.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have tried this and it only work with this date format `20170403`.

Comment: can you try to use bind_param ? $stmt->bind_param($_POST['abwesend_von'],$_POST['abwesend_bis'],$_POST['mitarbeiternummer_abwesenheit']); and then execute.

Comment: sorry: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_param() in ...` Maybe `bindParam()` method?